# Daylight Saving causing problems with highcart

Tags: c#, highcharts, dst

We are using a HighCharts to display some data with the x-axis being a DateTime; we need useUTC to be set to false `Highcharts.setOptions({ global: { useUTC: false } });`

When daylight saving stopped (OCT 27) we discovered that the hour 23:00-00:00 was repeated twice : with the second one displaying empty data. All the following data are shifted one hour forward.

Is there an easy way to handle this in HighCharts?

Comment: That's the problem with daylight savings - if you don't use UTC you'll have two hours of the day that are the same. Not a HighCharts problem, just a result of trying to visualize that data.

Comment: Your mistake is not using UTC. That means you will have to deal with timezones, rather then leaving it to he (propably better) existing code. And that way lies madness: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY My advise is to always store, retrieve and send datetimes in UTC.